# MYSQL Shell connect error from Command line

Tags: bash, shell, mysql

I am trying to connect to mysqlshell client from my linux command line
when I try to connect, using

```
mysqlsh mysql -h IP -u user -ppassword -e "show databases"
mysqlsh mysql -h IP:port -u user -ppassword -e "show databases"
mysqlsh mysql -h IP:port -u -port 3306 user -ppassword -e "show databases"
```

I get the below error.

Conflicting options: provided host differs from the host in the URI.

Could you please help with this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The proper format of `mysqlsh` is a bit different:

```
mysqlsh --user=user --password=password --port=5721 --host <hostname or IP>
```

Comment: This seems like just rearranging the same args and giving some of them double-hyphen notation instead of single-hyphen and an initial. It didn't change the error I'm getting at all. The question is, the host in *which* URI? I only see one hostname here so I need to know where it's reading a hostname from.

Comment: @Philip, please check carefully my and OP commands and you will see the difference.

Comment: Empirically I have a situation where neither the OP's format works nor does yours, and both fail in with the same message. Fortunately for some people your solution has worked. Funny enough my workaround was to use the `username@host` format and enter the password manually, but that's obviously not OK if full automation is needed.

Comment: @Philip, seems you have a questions. Feels free to ask it, explaining the situation in details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask Also if you have answer/solution answer own questions.